# Call to undefined function mysqli() in C:\wamp\www\admin\admin\sign.php on line 10

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

my code is here and my trying to signup user and if its already exits then dont insert  data
Call to undefined function mysqli() in C:\wamp\www\admin\admin\sign.php on line 10
Please help

```
<?php 
     session_start();
    require 'db.php';

    $x=$_POST['username'];
    $y=$_POST['password'];
    $z=$_POST['name'];


    $sql = mysqli("SELECT username FROM User WHERE username='$x'");
    $result=mysqli_query($sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0)
      {

    $sql ="INSERT INTO user(id, name, username, password) VALUES ('','$z','$x','$y')";
       $_SESSION['username'] = $x;


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully" . $_SESSION['username'];
        header('location:admin2.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

      }


    else
      {
     echo "Username already exists";

    }

        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: $sql = " SELECT username FROM User WHERE username='$x' "; replace this with your $sql variable

Comment: your code is mix with old mysql and mysqli

Comment: your code is wide open to **SQL Injection attacks** - please use parameterised statements to protect your data. also: **never ever ever ever** store unhashed passwords! use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: This question shows an utter lack of investigation, research, and care.  DOWNVOTE.  Always exhaustively search for solutions before posting a question on SO.  Read The Manual.  Please consider deleting this question because it is very low value and will serve no one else in the future.  (at least you are trying to use mysqli_ functions)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using a mix of procedural and object oriented ways of coding in PHP as to communicate with a MySQL database. Just stick to one. `mysqli()` is used to create a database connection in objected-oriented scheme and `mysqli_connect()` is used in procedural scheme. If you created a database connection using `mysqli()`, stick to objected-oriented schemes on how to retrieve, update and delete data.

Change  `$sql = mysqli("SELECT username FROM User WHERE username='$x'");` to

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM User WHERE username='$x'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `mysqli` in

```
$sql = mysqli("SELECT username FROM User WHERE username='$x'");
```

Although I'm not a user of `mysqli`, I think that it is not needed when you are just creating a variable with a query in it